# Camera viewpoint moves to inside 3D object

Tags: rendering, camera

I'm new to blender, I've checked other similar problems on this forum, however I dont see any that describe the problem I'm having.

I'm trying to change the viewpoint of the camera for an animated 3D model (glb) I'm editing.

In the viewport and the rendered image (Pic 1), it's fine, however when I export as glb and view in VR headset the viewpoint is now inside the model looking back (Pic 2).[image: Pic1]
[image: Pic 2]
I've tried changing so many things with no change in the final result. I'm sure it's something simple, but it's killing me!!

Please help!!

Comment: Any chance you have a second camera in your scene? The render view looks like it's from the perspective of the world origin - exactly where a new camera would be placed if it were added to the scene. OR, you may have accidentally used the "Make active camera" shortcut _(Ctrl+Num0)_ on some other object (The bones perhaps). To fix it, select the camera you know is "good", and make it the active camera by pressing _Ctrl+Num0_ again.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Yes there's only 1 camera and I've set it as the active one. I agree it seems as though it thinks the viewpoint is at the centre of the object, but I dont know how to change it. I changed the cameras position over and over but it never changes the view in the output model.

Comment: I have the exact same problem with a different model. And have tried deselecting "local camera', but nothing changes in the output model.